# Request only the header in http call

Tags: ruby, http, net-http, httpie

Is there a ruby library, with which I can request the web server to return only the header response and no content? This will help me speed up a script in which all I care is the response code.

I am now using this

```
Net::HTTP.get_response(URI(url))
```

but the server generates all the assert files and so on, which I do not want.

Comment: Your question as is (asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource), is off-topic. You may be able to make it on-topic by asking "how you can do it".

Comment: the question is clear enought to be understood and their is an example that specifies what I am using. thnks for sharing your idea though

Answer (score 0):

You might use `rest-client` gem and in particular `head` method.
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rest-client/rest-client/RestClient#head-class_method

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using 'Net::HTTP::Head' in the net-http library. other libraries also support it, just remember to look for the `HEAD` method instead of the `Get` method